# Do I need to use partpobe and mkfs or can parted format the partition as ext4 automatically?

Tags: partition, parted

I am trying to create a single partition using `parted` command in Linux with ext4 file system using below command non interactively

```
parted /dev/sdc --script -- mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
```

Could someone please tell me do I need to run below commands after this or will it be taken care of automatically by parted command itself.

```
partprobe
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`parted` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/mkpart.html#mkpart), the `mkpart` command creates a partition *without creating a filesystem on it*.

You might or might not need to run `partprobe` afterwards, depending on the versions of the kernel and `parted` used. Older versions might need it, newer ones generally won't. However, running it should not be harmful in any case.

But if you want to keep the partition you just created, your `mkfs` command should then be:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1      # not /dev/sdc
```

If you wanted to use the disk in a so-called "superfloppy" configuration, it is certainly possible to just run `mkfs` on the whole-disk device `/dev/sdc` and use it like that. But then there would be no point in partitioning it first, as creating the filesystem like that will overwrite the freshly created partition table.

Having a partition table on the disk that is recognizable on most common operating systems makes it safer to move disks between systems: it avoids the possibility that another operating system (I'm looking towards Redmond...) would not recognize the disk as already containing data, and might offer to helpfully format it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear cut answer..It helps a lot!!